# Techniques for NER

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I might sound really nooby for asking this but I'm writing a report about Named Entity Recognition for University and our lecturer wants us to provide techniques and tools required in NER. I think I've got my tools sorted with SpaCy, NLTK and Stanford NLP but I'm not quite sure what he means by techniques. Would the techniques mean tokenization? tagging? or aren't those proper techniques.

Cheers

Comment: See if you can structure your question a bit clearer - do you need to know if those are valid techniques at all, or how to use the techniques.

Comment: Okay, sorry if it was a bit unclear. Yeah I need to know if those are valid techniques to use.

It's a report so I dont need to code anything, just wondering if those are what my lecturer meant by techniques

Answer (score 0):

First: Named Entity Recognition is an Activity of Natural Language Processing.

Techniques are ways to achieve something. For example, there are several ways to do Part of Speech Tagging, which is another Activity of Natural Language Processing. As an example, POS tagging can be rule based, based on Machine Learning or based on dependency parsing.

The same goes for Named Entity Recognition - there are several techniques, and even several different algorithms, that can achieve it. It's your work to find out which.